# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::updateSlider(), 1 passed in.... on line 54 and exactly 2 expected - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I got an error

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::updateSlider(), 1 passed in E:\localhost\JMS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected

**Controller**

```
public function updateSlider(Request $request,$id)           
{     
    $this->validate(request(),[
            
        //put fields to be validated here
        ]);    
    $oldImage=DB::table('slider')->where('id',$id)->first();
    $oldFile=$oldImage->image;
    $task=array();
    $current_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $task['updated_at']=$current_date_time;
    
    $file=$request->file('image');
    $file_name=hexdec(uniqid());
    $ext=strtolower($file->getClientOriginalExtension());
    $file_full_name=$file_name.'.'.$ext;
    $upload_path='Gallery/';
    $file_url=$upload_path.$file_full_name;
    $success=$file->move($upload_path,$file_full_name);
    $task['photo']=$file_url;
    
    $data=DB::table('slider')->update($task);
    if ($data) {
        unlink($oldFile);
        return back()->with('success', 'Photo Has Been Saved Successfully.');

    }
}
```

Here is the form

```
<form action="{{ url('admin/slider/update/.$data->id') }}" method="POST"enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    @csrf                       
    <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input" >             
    <button type="submit"class="btn btn-primary">Update </i></button>      
</form>
```

Comment: This is about where you _call_ the method, apparently there you have passed only one argument, instead of the required two.

Comment: Show the code where you call the function.

Comment: `<form action="{{ url('admin/slider/update/.$data->id') }}" method="POST"enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
   
                  <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input" >

  
        <button type="submit"class="btn btn-primary">Update </i></button>

    </form>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<form action="{{ url('admin/slider/update/.$data->id') }}" blabla>
```

Try this:

```
<form action="/admin/slider/update/{{ $data->id }}" blabla>
```